# Is it possible to turn a context pattern into a Gallina function?

Tags: coq, ltac

In Ltac, a context pattern can be used to build an *Ltac-level* function which accepts a Gallina term and constructs a Gallina term by filling in a hole. I would like to reify this function and use it at the level of Gallina, rather than Ltac.

E.g., the following code works using meta-variables rather than context patterns.

```
Variables 
  (A : Set)
  (P : A -> Prop)
  (a : A)
  (H : forall Q: A -> Prop, Q a).


Goal (P a).
match goal with
  | |- ?P a => exact (H P)
end.
Qed.
```

But the following code does not work because I cannot bring the variable `x` into scope before filling in the pattern:

```
Goal (P a).
match goal with
  | |- context C[a] => let y := context C[x] in exact (H (fun x => y))
end.
(* The reference x was not found in the current
environment. *)
```

Nor does the following work because I cannot use Ltac within Gallina:

```
Goal (P a).
match goal with
  | |- context C[a] => let y := exact (H (fun x => context C[x]))
end.
(* Syntax error... *)
```

But the following code shows that my context pattern works like I think it should:

```
Goal (P a).
match goal with
  | |- context C[a] => let y := context C[a] in idtac y
end.
(* (P a) *)
```

While this example is trivial because the goal is a single application, in general I want to use context patterns to match significantly more complex goals and then use those patterns to build Gallina functions. Can this be done?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're doing here, but the correct way to use Ltac in Gallina is like `... ltac:(...) ...`.

Comment: `ltac:(...)` to my knowledge is only applicable to override the ltac parser when it expects Gallina. I want to use ltac from within Gallina because the tactic requires variables locally scoped in the Gallina term I'm writing.

Comment: No, `ltac:` is general purpose "fill this hole by executing a tactic." See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ltac:(...)`

```
match goal with
  | |- context C[a] => exact (H (fun x => ltac:(let y := context C[x] in exact y)))
end.
```

`ltac:(...)` can replace any Gallina term. The expected type of that hole becomes the goal for the contained tactic expression, which is executed to produce a new Gallina term to fill the hole.